# Dynamically allocating memory in class constructor

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to implement a class in C++ used to store the data of an optimization problem. The data is saved in a text file, and is of the form

- n #number of rows
- m #number of columns
- c_ij #matrix of cost coefficients

So I do not know the dimensions of the problem before I read the file wherefore I need to allocate memory dynamically. What I have done so far is to publicly declare a pointer

```
int** C;
```

in the header file. And then in the constructor in the .cpp file I do

```
ifstream InFile( fname );
InFile >> n;
InFile >> m;
int** C = (int**) calloc(n, sizeof(int *));
for(int i=0; i<n; ++i){
  C[i] == (int*) calloc(m,sizeof(int));
  for(int j=0, j<m; ++j){
    InFile >> C[i][j];
  }
}
```

where `fname` is the data file given as an argument to the constructor. The problem occurs when I in a member function, call it `ProcessData()` try to access this pointer to the pointer to the integer array. It seems it changes address! When I do

```
cout << C;
```

In the constructor I get

```
0000000000359300
```

However, when I do the same in the member function I get

```
000000013F57710C100
```

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?
I am using Visual C++ in Visual Studio on a 64 bit Windows 7 machine.

Comment: C is a local variable, so you can't possibly be accessing it from a member function.

Comment: Did you really mean to use `calloc()` rather than `new[]`? Also I would not recommend doing all this in the constructor. I would set the pointers to `nullptr` or `0` in the constructor (to give them valid state) and write a separate `load()` function to initialize the specific problem data.

Comment: @Galik: You make it sound like `new[]` is better than `calloc`. It's not.

Comment: I know that I should not manage the memory my self, but the code I am writing has to be compatible with some older C-code from my supervisor. @Galik why don't you like having all the stuff in the constructor? Is it a problem, bad practice or a personal opinion?

Comment: The more things you put in the constructor the more likely it is to fail/throw an exception. Its often more awkward dealing with error conditions during the construction (no return type / auto-construction in containers etc...) and remember the **destructor** will **not** get called if your constructor fails. So many feel it is best to use constructors only to put your object into a minimal **valid** state in the safest, most easily recoverable way. Then if a separate initialization function fails the object can remain in its **valid** constructed state for a retry (for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
int** C = (int**) calloc(n, sizeof(int *));
```

is declaring a new (local) variable and initializing it. To set the value of the member variable, just remove the declaration bit:

```
C = (int**) calloc(n, sizeof(int *));
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, do not ever manage your own memory in C++. You can simply use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` to manage it for you, which actually has a chance in hell of being correct.

Secondly, in the constructor, C is a local variable, so it cannot possibly have the same address as any other variable existing at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is for your class to have a member vector. Vectors wrap the process of having a pointer and dynamically allocating memory to it, and they behave properly when you copy, move or destroy your object:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    std::vector< std::vector<int> > C;

    MyClass(size_t rows, size_t cols):
        C( rows, std::vector<int>(cols, 0) )
    { }
};
```

It's probably a bad idea to do your user input inside the constructor; instead do the input (and check for success) and then construct the object:

```
size_t rows, cols;
if ( !(inFile >> rows >> cols) )
    throw std::runtime_error("input error");

MyClass obj(rows, cols);
```